# How to synchronize hidden (dot) files in owncloud/nextcloud

Tags: hidden-files, nextcloud, owncloud-client

When using ownCloud client for linux my hidden files are not synchronized, and appear under `Activity > Not Synced` with a message stating:

> File is ignored because it's hidden

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option to allow hidden files in ownCloud client. Simply edit the configuration file: `~/.local/share/data/ownCloud` and set:

`0\Folders\ownCloud\ignoreHiddenFiles=false`

There is also a common list of files to exclude: `/etc/owncloud-client/sync-exclude.lst`; which includes temporary files, htaccess, locks, etc.

These can also be set from the GUI: `General > Edit Ignored Files`

Comment: Note that they cannot sync .htaccess files for security reasons.